# Sharing file for reading and writing in .NET

Tags: .net

I am trying to figure the FileAccess / FileShare combination that will allow me opening a file for reading, and then opening it for writing. So far the next two lines of the test code are giving me `UnauthorizedAccessException` on the second line:

```
Stream s1 = File.Open(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
Stream s2 = File.Open(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

In real life I have a web application which (server side) uses certain ZIP with data. Several handlers are taking files from this archive, and one handler tries to update it. So in practice these two lines are most likely to be in the different threads of the same IIS Application Pool.

Comment: I am an idiot - the file I was trying to write was read-only. So this code works, as well as the advice of Lucas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FileShare.ReadWrite` for both streams.

`FileShare.Read` basically means: *disallow any other write handle*, and since there is one from the first line, the second line fails.